# Is there a more modern version of the idiom "as the crow flies"?

Tags: idioms

"As the crow flies" or "as the bird flies" means the most direct path between two points, not accounting for streets and obstacles one on the ground would have to account for.

The idiom feels dated. Is there a more modern saying that means the same thing?

Comment: Not really a saying but "in a straight line" works

Comment: I'm not sure there is any better phrase meaning distance measured by a ruler on the map (as opposed to distance that a person has to travel in practice, accounting for the indirect layout of thoroughfares and so on). I wouldn't say the idiom is dated - it is quite regularly heard and the meaning and context of use appear to be very specific.

Comment: What makes you think it's "dated"? There are still crows, are there not?

Comment: Straight as an arrow!

Comment: You will say "The length of the rhumb line joining the following points..." Then you give the coordinates and specify the datum. This sounds more modern.

Answer (score 2):

The modern phrase I've heard for this is "straight line distance"

> It's five hundred miles from A to B as the crow flies
>
> The straight line distance from A to B is five hundred miles.

Comment: How about "as Google gives it"?